# Получить данные по товару через API с Amazon shop и bookdepository.com

Tags: php-curl

Требуется с сайтов по параметру получить данные по товару. Проблема в том, что Amazon вообще зарыл документацию по api, да еще и названия не говорящие дает. А для bookdepository.com google вообще api  не ищет (возможно, его и нет).
Подскажите где в Amazon провести регистрацию (у них сервисов до тучи), далее найду там ключ, и где бы еще документацию посмотреть.

Понимаю, что вопрос, может показаться абсурдым, но я пока найти ответа не могу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Подскажите где в Amazon провести регистрацию (у них сервисов до тучи)

[Ссылка на регистрацию аккаунта, в котором можно получить ключ](https://portal.aws.amazon.com/billing/signup?nc2=h_ct&src=header_signup&redirect_url=https%3A%2F%2Faws.amazon.com%2Fregistration-confirmation&language=ru_ru#/start)

Comment: Спасибо, я там уже был, но немного не разобрался. Через некоторое время дошло, что это их политика дебильная (ввести номер карты для годового использования, что для тестовых задач для меня неприемлемо). Отмечу ваш ответ как ответ на вопрос (хотя он и так реально отвечает на мой размытый вопрос). Спасибо вам!